# How do you fix debug assertion failed?

Tags: c, runtime-error, assert

I'm making a C program that is changing all the non alphabet questions to a space. But when I run it I get the debug assertion failed message. How can I solve it?
Here is my code:

```
int main(void) {
    FILE* txtFileR = fopen("alg3file.txt", "r");
    FILE* txtFileW = fopen("destAlg3.txt", "w");

    int c;

    while ((c = fgetc(txtFileR)) != EOF) {
        if (isalpha(c)==0 && c!='\n') {
            c = ' ';
        }
        fputc(c, txtFileW);
    }
    fclose(txtFileR);
    fclose(txtFileW);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazingly enough *in a debugger*. If that assertion failed find out what the conditions are and why they were violated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that we can copy and run ourselves (hint: you need a `int main()` function at the very least) and the entire error message as text, not an image.

Comment: `char c;` -> `char` is not able to handle EOF and `fgetc` wants an `int`, switch to `int c;`

Comment: I fixed the minor things you commented but it still doesn't work. When I write to the file it only comes maybe 1/10th of the whole file, is that because of the debug assertion failure or because of the fact that it's so inefficient?

Comment: @tadman: Assuming that the file streams are buffered, a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) to the kernel should not be necessary on every call to `fgetc`. Most calls will be handled in [user-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space). Only when the buffer is empty will a new system call be necessary, which will fill the buffer again.

Comment: I see nothing wrong in the code you posted that could cause this assertion to appear after processing 1/10th of the file.  Therefore, my only explanation is that the information you provided is not fully true. I suspect that you either did not post your actual source code (but rather a simplified version of it) or that your statement that it successfully processes 1/10th of the file is not correct. For example, one explanation for this error message could be that `fopen` failed and returned `NULL`, but this is contradictory to your statement that it only happens after 1/10th of the file.

Comment: @Creepzzz: An inefficenty would only cause your program to run more slowly, but not fail completely. Therefore, I wouldn't worry about efficiency until you have found the error.

Comment: Add checks to make sure your files were opened successfully.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel you are correct, I added an if-statement that checked if the files were null and it turned out that the file I attempted to read from was null. I will try to figure out how the hell that happend

Comment: I put both my files where my main.c file were and realized I had doubled my files, those I deleted and then it worked. Thank you all for your patience with me. I'm quite new to programming.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, one of your `fopen` calls failed and returned a NULL FILE *.  When you pass that `fgetc` or `fputc`, you get undefined behavior, which in your case shows up as a debug assertion about an invalid stream.